# Program crashes at printf

Tags: c, crash, printf

This program compares two strings: one that is the good one and the other that is input by the user (I did this with four strings, so two of them are inputs and the other two are the right answers).
I read that the function `gets` should not be used and it's better to use `fgets` instead. So, that's what I did here but when my program reaches the second `printf`, it crashes.

The source code is as shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char clave_verdadera[5], usuario_verdadero[5];
    strcpy(clave_verdadera, "hola\n");
    strcpy(usuario_verdadero, "jose\n");

    char *clave, *usuario;
    printf("por favor escriba su nombre de usuario:");
    fgets(usuario, 5, stdin);

    printf("Por favor escriba su contraseña: ");
    fgets(clave, 5, stdin);

    int comparacion_clave;
    comparacion_clave = strcmp(clave, clave_verdadera);
    int comparacion_usuario;
    comparacion_usuario = strcmp(usuario, usuario_verdadero);

    comparacion_clave == 0 && comparacion_usuario == 0
    ? printf("¡Felicidades! has entrado \n"): printf("Nombre de usuario o  contraseña incorrecta \n");


    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Answer (score 4):

```
fgets(usuario, 5, stdin);
```

`usuario` is a pointer and is not pointing to any valid memory location and you are trying to write to it which will lead to undefined behavior.

Allocate memory before writing to this location.

```
usuario = malloc(size);/* size depends on your requirement */
```

There are other issues also which needs to be handled like Array should be large enough to hold `\0` character which is not taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

```
char *clave, *usuario;
```

It makes `*clave` and `*usuario` are pointers who do not point to any valid memory (does not hold a valid address) in virtual address space, and then through `fgets` you are trying to modify value written at that particular (invalid) address location, which invokes undefined behaviour.
So change that to,

```
char *clave = NULL, *usuario = NULL;
```

and allocate the required length of memory dynamically using `malloc`.

Apart from that, you have declared these variables here,

```
char clave_verdadera[5], usuario_verdadero[5];
```

And in `fgets(usuario, 5, stdin);` you are copying a string into them,

```
strcpy(clave_verdadera, "hola\n");
strcpy(usuario_verdadero, "jose\n");
```

To accommodate that in the `char` arrays you need to have them like,

```
char clave_verdadera[6], usuario_verdadero[6]; //5 for "hola\n" and 1 for '\0'
```